# I am facing this android exception when i run android application on (Android-1.6) device and application is build in android platform(2.2

Tags: android, exception

I am facing this android exception when i run android application on (Android-1.6) device and application is build in android platform(2.2)..do you have any solution to fix this exception if so please replay...

exception shows on logcat....is

04-12 19:45:30.498: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476): java.lang.VerifyError: org.exmp.pickcontactquicksms.Controller
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
04-12 19:45:30.549: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I do not think that's possible. You can run an application made for 1.6 on a device with 2.2, but not the other way around...

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can run an application made for 1.6 on a device with 2.2, but not the other way around...